# A bus routing puzzle, does it ring a bell?

Tags: latch, bus, routing, tri-state, function

I am breaking my head over a puzzling bus routing puzzle, and I wonder if this sort of problem rings a bell. I have 4 memory cell ports, let's call them EE, OE, EO, and OO, that are being mapped to 4 ports, let's call them A, B, C, and D. Those ports you may call "variables" if you wish. These variables are the inputs and outputs to 4 different arithmetic / logical functions, each of which compute the next value for one variable, depending on one or more of he other variables, applying a different arithmetic / logical function for each of the 4 ports, but for each port it is always the same, though different between the different ports.

```
A = Fa(B,C,D)
B = Fb(B,A,C)
C = Fc(C,A,B)
D = Fd(D,A)
```

where Fa, Fb, Fc, Fd are some functions, composed of adders, and, or, xor gates and inverters.

Now, in the simplest case, EE is mapped to A, OE to B, EO to C, and OO to D.

[image]

All these computations happen in parallel, are "hard wired" in the most literal sense of the word, and are supposed to happen in parallel, I know that anything can be programmed in software, but that's not the point. The functions are hard-wired.

These "ports" or "variables", A, B, C, and D are realized transparent latches, so that in one phase they show the data coming from the memory cells EE, OE, EO, and OO respectively, that then are latched so the results of the computation are held, coming out on a tri-state buffer and then re-routed back to the memory cells while the Write Enable (!WE) signal is low to write the results back into the memory cells.

Let me show this principle for one of the memory cells and ports for one bit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWcZ3I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That buffer on Fout is supposed to be a tri-state buffer, and so you can see that the result is presented on that line from Di/o of the memory OE while the latch is held and the memory !WE is low to write into the memory cell. This is simply done on the low phase of the clock. Whatever inverters can translate that to any real chips signal sense and clock cycle. But that is the essence of it and pretty straight forward.

Now comes the puzzle. The mapping between the memory cells and the "variables" A, B, C, and D is dynamic, it has 4 states which the system will assume, in some rotation of cycles. The diagram I just showed is the basic state 1. I will show state 2 and 3 and 4 now in a simplified diagram without these arcs between the variable nodes, just the connection between the memory cells and the variables:

[image: mapping state 2]

[image: mapping state 3]

[image: mapping state 4]

Another way of thinking about this mapping is of course a matrix:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |EE|OE|EO|OO|
+--+--+--+--+--+
| A| 1| 2| 3| 4|
| B| 2| 1| 4| 3|
| C| 3| 4| 1| 2|
| D| 4| 3| 2| 1|
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

These 4 mapping states are the only ones that matter. And I've been looking at this for two days with the intuition that it should be possible to have a minimal set of bi-directional multiplexers or just bus transceivers which one might arrange in such a way as to enumerate all 4 mapping paths. Since there are 4 combinations, some sort of 2-level cross-over network should be possible. Since my values are 4-bit, I'm thinking that 8-bit bus transceivers could be arranged in such a way that I can switch them over like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPPGjJ.png)</sup>

You see, I use 2 octal bus transceivers, one of them has EE-A and OE-B connected straight through (symbolized by "=" and the other crossed over (symbolized by "X"). Either one or the other is selected. The DIRection input from K to L for in the read-phase, and reversed, L to K, in the write-phase.

This works for one case and for two of these "variable" ports. Add another transceiver for EO, and OO to C and D respectively and I can build the mapping states 1 and 2. Now for 3 and 4.

Now, my intuition is that perhaps I can get away with two such cross overs in series to generate the 4 mapping states

```
+-----+-----+-------+
|xovr1|xovr2|mapping|
| =/x | =/x | state |
+-----+-----+-------+
|  =  |  =  |   1   |
|  =  |  x  |   2   |
|  x  |  =  |   3   |
|  x  |  x  |   4   |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

It seems like that's what it should take, but as many papers as I have scribbled full with the possible arrangements I still haven't figured it out. You might say, "I have my wires crossed."

I wonder if this problem rings a bell with anyone? It seems like something that has been invented before to create paths, such as, I'm thinking, redundant server and disk networks and fail-over paths, perhaps.

Hmmm.... I think I have it. I leave the question up here though because I really want to know if it rings a bell, if this is a problem that's been discussed in the engineering world.

Comment: it is not completely clear to me what you are trying to do, but i think that two 74LS153 dual 4-input multiplexer IC would work for the mapping, if i am understanding it correctly .... one quad 4 input multiplexer would also work